# Carmen-rails select US as default country

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

Ok this is driving me crazy!!  I used selected: 'US' to default the selected country to united states - however - it wont populate the state/province until a changed event.  You'd think this was a simple jquery fix and maybe it is but how in the heck do you populate the province from the selected: country when the page loads?  Below is the jquery

```
if $('select#cause_country').exists()
    $('select#cause_country').change (event) ->
      select_wrapper = $('#cause_state_code_wrapper')
      $('select', select_wrapper).attr('disabled', true)
      country_code = $(this).val()
      url = "/causes/subregion_options?parent_region=#{country_code}"
      select_wrapper.load(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this code after your if end :

```
$('select#cause_country').trigger("change")
```

this will trigger `change` event when the select form is shown, see [jQuery/trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

don't forget to add it after the end of your if statement :

```
if $('select#cause_country').exists()
    $('select#cause_country').change (event) ->
      select_wrapper = $('#cause_state_code_wrapper')
      $('select', select_wrapper).attr('disabled', true)
      country_code = $(this).val()
      url = "/causes/subregion_options?parent_region=#{country_code}"
      select_wrapper.load(url)
$('select#cause_country').trigger("change")
```

Hope this help you